# Get size of files and folders of a path and store it in a python dictionary

Tags: python-3.x, file, dictionary, directory

The result I want is to have the size of everithing in the path I choose from the file to the root folder, and stored it in a python dictionary like this:

```
{
    root:{
        folder1:{
            {file11:100,
             file12:89,
             file13:32},
             size:221
        },
        folder2:{
            subfolder21:{
                {file21:45,
                 file22:80},
                size:125
            },
            size:125
        },
        size:346,
    }
}
```

Like this I know that the file11 in root/folder1 it's size is 100, also I have the total size of the folder1 that is the sum of everything in it, 221

I manage to get this dictionary

```
{
    root:{
        folder1:{
            {file11:100,
             file12:89,
             file13:32}
        },
        folder2:{
            subfolder21:{
                {file21:45,
                 file22:80}
            }
        }
    }
}
```

But I am struggling a lot to calculate the sum of the files and assign the values to each folder, my code is:

```
def get_dir_content(ls_path):
    for dir_path in os.listdir(ls_path):
        if dir_path.isFile():
            yield (dir_path.path, dir_path.size)
        elif dir_path.isDir() and ls_path != dir_path.path:
            yield from get_dir_content(dir_path.path)
            
x = list(get_dir_content("/path"))

d = {}
for i in x:
    l = ''
    for j in i[0].split('/'):
        l = l+"['"+j+"']" 
        try:
            exec('d'+l)
        except:
            exec('d'+l+'={}')
    exec('d'+l+'='+str(i[1]))
```

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Try this.

```
def get_dir_content(ls_path, d):
    for dir_path in os.listdir(ls_path):
        if dir_path.isFile():
            d[dir_path.path] = dir_path.size
            yield (dir_path.path, dir_path.size)
        elif dir_path.isDir() and ls_path != dir_path.path:
            sub_dir = {dir_path.path: {}}
            d.update(sub_dir)
            yield from get_dir_content(dir_path.path, d[dir_path.path])

def get_sum(d):
    for key, value in d.items():
        if isinstance(value, dict):
            d[key]['size'] = get_sum(value)
        else:
            d[key] = {'size': value}
    return sum(v['size'] for v in d.values())

x = list(get_dir_content("/path", d))
d['root']['size'] = get_sum(d['root'])

print(d)
```

If I'm understanding your question correctly: This code first iterates through the files and folders in the given path using the `get_dir_content()` function. It then checks if the item is a file or a directory and stores the corresponding path and size in a dictionary.

If the item is a directory, a sub-dictionary is created and the `get_dir_content()` function is called recursively to iterate through the files and folders in the directory.

The `get_sum()` function is then called to calculate the total size of the directory by summing up the sizes of the files and folders in the dictionary. Finally, the size of the root directory is calculated and stored in the dictionary.

Comment: Hi @meoww, thanks for the answer, for using your code what should it be "d" first define? I ran it with d={} but I am getting a different structured from the one I want

Comment: Yes, I iterate to get all the structure of the folders, subfolder, and finally the files and sizes